# Convert Nepali Unicode to Plain Text in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

How can I convert Nepali unicode to plain text in C#?

For eg: I have Nepali unicode

```
म भात खान्छु
```

How can I convert it to

```
Ma Bhat Khanchu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to "convert" from one character set to another.  What you need to do is to transliterate from Devanagari.  A quick google search didn't turn up a C# library, but from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration) it looks like it should be fairly straightforward to implement.

Your code will look something like this

```
String Transliterate(map<char,string> table,String input)
{
    StringBuilder builder;
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
       builder.append(table[c]);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

With `table` built from the mappings listed in wikipedia or some other source.

Answer (score 0):

try the following...

```
It depends on the encoding of your string ([ASCII][1], [UTF][1]-8, ...).
```

For example:

```
byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (myString);
byte[] b2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (myString);
```

A small sample why encoding matters:

```
string pi = "\u03a0";
byte[] ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (pi);
byte[] utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (pi);

Console.WriteLine (ascii.Length); //Will print 1
Console.WriteLine (utf8.Length); //Will print 2
Console.WriteLine (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString (ascii));
```

//Will print '?'

ASCII simply isn't equipped to deal with special characters.

Internally, the .NET framework uses [UTF-16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx) to represent strings, so if you simply want to get the exact bytes that .NET uses, use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes (...).`

See Character [Encoding in the .NET Framework (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx) for more information.

Comment: How to represent
म भात खान्छु 
in byte[]bytes?